# Firebase not updating values

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using a `FirebaseManager` singleton class to fetch data from Firebase. I'm calling `getAllCharts` in my `ViewController`, which needs this data. I receive the data initially, but when I update my data in firebase it won't update the values in the app (`getAllCharts()` is **never** called).

> FirebaseManager:

```
final class FirebaseManager {

    static let sharedInstance = FirebaseManager()

    private init() {}

    private let reference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    private var charts = [ChartRepresentable]()

    func getAllCharts(completionHandler: ((_ charts: [ChartRepresentable]) -> ())? = nil) {

        guard let path = FirebasePath.allCharts.path else {
            return
        }

        guard charts.isEmpty else {
            completionHandler?(charts)
            return
        }

        reference.child(path).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.hasChildren() {

                var availableCharts = [ChartRepresentable]()

                for child in snapshot.children {

                    guard let chartSnapshot = child as? FIRDataSnapshot else {
                        continue
                    }

                    switch chartSnapshot.key {
                    case "bar":
                        availableGraphs.append(BarChart(snapshot: chartSnapshot))
                    case "line":
                        availableGraphs.append(LineChart(snapshot: chartSnapshot))
                    default: break
                    }
                }

                self.charts = availableCharts
                completionHandler?(self.charts)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

> ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var setupCards: [SetupCard]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        FirebaseManager.sharedInstance.getAllCharts { [weak self] (charts) in
            self?.setupCards = [SetupCard(charts: charts)]
            self?.setupView.collectionView.reloadData()
            self?.setupView.pageControl.numberOfPages = self?.setupCards?.count ?? 0
        }
}
```

How do I get the updates?

Comment: Tried removing `[weak self]` from `FirebaseManager.sharedInstance.getAllCharts` completion block?

Comment: @ZaidPathan I tried that but it's still the same issue

Comment: Also have you added break point below `reference.child(path).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in` then changed the value on Firebase and checked?

Comment: @ZaidPathan Setting the breakpoint only works for the initial call, this is when ViewDidLoad is called. At that moment of time I can fetch data only once, but when I update values after that point my getAllCharts won't get called, setting a breakpoint at that moment has no effect (I tried that)

Comment: @ZaidPathan I "fixed" it, I called this getAllCharts() method in AppDelegate too, since I want to download data while the app is starting up, removing this call in AppDelegate makes everything work .. although I have no idea why it does work now (I'd rather have it downloading in AppDelegate first)

Comment: i have faced same issue because of internet speed.

Comment: @Hapeki Nice 